# Change ListView item base on condition

Tags: wpf, listview

I have `ListView` with my object and one of my object properties is of `bool` value:

```
<GridViewColumn Width="100" Header="FileCheck " DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding IsFileOK}" />
```

Instead of displaying this variable value (true or false) how can I replace this with my own text and my own color ?

For example:

File is OK // green color

File damage // red color

This is what i have try:

```
<Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsFileOK}" Value="false">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green" />
        </DataTrigger>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsFileOK}" Value="true">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red" />
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this one

```
<ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
 <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
   <Style.Triggers>
     <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsFileOK}" Value="False">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green" />
     </DataTrigger>
     <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsFileOK}" Value="True">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red" />
     </DataTrigger>
  </Style.Triggers>
 </Style>
</ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
```

Comment: that's works but i want 2 things: 1: change only the text color of this specific column and not all the row. 2: replace the bool value (true\false) with text of my own

Comment: @VerintVerint then use Foreground Instead of Background property and You can change that bool to string but It should match with Value. For an example property value is "TestOk" means Value also should be "TestOk"

Comment: Again Foreground will change the whole row color and i want only the specific column color.

Answer (score 0):

Idea is to modify the background and text using Style and Triggers.
e.g.

```
<ListView.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Blue"></Setter>
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"></Setter>
                    </Trigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </ListView.Resources>
```

So you can replace `Trigger` with `DataTrigger` to use properties from view model.

Answer (score 0):

Use below code to achieve this,

```
<ListView.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Blue"></Setter>
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsFileOK}" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"></Setter>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </ListView.Resources>
```